# How to output log in MS Unit Testing Framework VS 2010

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, mstest

I am trying to log some information while the unit test is running in MS Unit Testing Framework VS 2010.

I tried Trace.WriteLine, Console.WriteLine and Debug.WriteLine but I am not able to see the output in the output window.

Any idea how to do it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure your test class contains the following:

```
private TestContext testContextInstance;

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the test context which provides
/// information about and functionality for the current test run.
/// </summary>
public TestContext TestContext
{
    get
    {
        return testContextInstance;
    }
    set
    {
        testContextInstance = value;
    }
}
```

Then you can call:

```
this.testContextInstance.WriteLine("Hello World");
```

Comment: As mentioned below: this is not visible in the 'output' window, but in the "test results" window.

Comment: Classic Microsoft API LOLs.

Answer (score 11):

The output from the test case is *not* visible in visual studio's output window. Rather it is visible in the "test results window". In the test result window, you should double click on the result of the test case *(Passed/addTest row in the picture)* for which you want to see the output and there you will see the all your writeLines.

[image]

Comment: Thanks tjRobinson and Assem Bansal. This is what I was looking for

Comment: And in Visual Studio 2013 it's under "Output" for each test in the Test Explorer.